# Explain the sum of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} i^n = \frac{1}{1-i}$

How is this the case? I can't find any reference to this anywhere but I know it can be used to solve the question:

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n-1}} = 4$

By differentiating the formula so that the left sides match (after some rearranging)

But I don't undertsand how the initial formula is true?

Comment: This is called a geometric series and converges when $|i| < 1$. It's also probably bad notation to choose $i$ here since this formula still works for complex numbers with the absolute value replaced by the modulus.

Comment: So only in this case is the above the true then? That would make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N} r^n$ (i.e. $S_N = 1 + r + \dotsb + r^N$).
Then
$$ \begin{align*} 
S_N &= 1 + r + r^2 + \dotsb + r^N \\
r S_N &= \phantom{1+{}}r+r^2+\dotsb + r^{N} + r^{N+1}
\end{align*}$$
So subtracting,
$$ (1-r)S_N = 1-r^{N+1} \\
S_N = \frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}. $$
Now, your sum is $\lim_{N \to \infty} S_N = \frac{1}{1-r}$, provided $|r|<1$.

Comment: That's great - thanks!